# Lucene - Error trying to index a simple document

Tags: java, lucene

Hi I am getting an odd error while trying to implement lucene search (indexing).

What I am doing is simple:
1. I am initializing an analyzer and the indexwriterconfig
2. Initialize the index writer and a single document 
3. Add the document to the index writer  <-- -breaks here!  Why....?  error below

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: TokenStream contract violation:
>   reset()/close() call missing, reset() called multiple times, or
>   subclass does not call super.reset(). Please see Javadocs of
>   TokenStream class for more information about the correct consuming
>   workflow."

Related Code:

```
        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LATEST);
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, analyzer);


        //set indexing methodology
        if (bCreate) {
            //removing any previously indexed documents:
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
        } else {
            // Add new documents to an existing index:
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
        }

          IndexWriter iwWriter = new IndexWriter(FSDirectory.open(new File( strIndexPath )), iwc);
          Document doc = new Document();

          //Fields that are NOT searchable
          doc.add(new StringField("AppID", strAppId, Field.Store.YES));
          doc.add(new StringField("Url", strUrl, Field.Store.YES));

          //Fields that ARE searchable
          doc.add(new TextField("AppName", strAppName, Field.Store.YES));
          doc.add(new TextField("AppDescription", strAppDescription, Field.Store.YES));

          iwWriter.addDocument(doc); //   <-- breaks here!!!
```

Comment: Do you ever call reset?

Comment: I can not reproduce this in Lucene 4.10.2.  Might you be missing some pertinent code?  Or could you have an incorrect version of some Lucene jar in your build path perhaps?

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono - Doesn't look like he's ever accessing a `TokenStream` directly.  Direct handling of TokenStreams is somewhat advanced, and usually quite unnecessary.  This is bog standard Lucene document indexing.  The `IndexWriter` should handle navigating the TokenStream without him having to worry about it.

Comment: No I never call reset, do I need to?

Comment: @femtoRgon You are right, my mistake.

Comment: @JohnSmith No. I don't think you should, femtoRon corrected me.

Comment: In my path I have lucene-core-4.10.2.jar

Comment: I faced the same issue, but in my case, I was using Lucene 4.9 in my project, however this project was referencing another one containing the jars from Lucene 4.3, which, somehow got my compiler confused. I removed those jars from the other project and everything works fine now.